# Salt: file.replace on a list of files (globbing)

Tags: saltstack

I use [file.replace](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.replace) and would like to use this not on a single file, but on a list of files. The list of files comes from globbing.

Example: I want to modify `/etc/ImageMagick*/policy.xml`.

The file can be `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` or `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml` or ...

AFAIK "name" in "file.replace" can only be one single file name.

How to solve this with salt?

Related discussion at salt-users list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/75OpiflpObA

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in two steps:

1. Get a list of files that match your search with `file.find`
2. Make a loop to apply your function `file.replace` to each files in that list

Note: This is only the methodology to achieve your goal, I don't have the technical solution ready for you.

Comment: Looks good, but a working solution would be great.

Comment: Did you manage to do what you wanted ?

Comment: no, I found something (and wrote it as answer). But this solution has a drawback: The file needs to already exist before the salt run starts, since jinia gets executed before the salt run starts. (see below)

Comment: `file.find` creates a list of files. But AFAIK this list of files gets created before the first action/requisite gets executed. This means it does not work, since one salt run should do two things: Install RPM, then change a file which was created by installing the rpm. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
/etc/foo.test:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://tmp/dummy

{% for file in salt['cmd.run']('ls -1 /etc/foo*.test').splitlines() %}
{{ file }}_dummy_to_real:
  file.replace:
    - name: {{ file }}
    - pattern: dummy
    - repl: hitme
{% endfor %}
```

But it only works, if `/etc/foo.test` already exists before salt starts executing.

If  `/etc/foo.test` gets created during the same salt run, then this will fail.

Comment: The solution has the fundamental issue, that jinja gets executed too early :-(